# Do people use classes as their "game loop?"

Tags: c++

So I've been learning how to program so I can make games, and, therefor, I've been reading and watching many tutorials.  Every once in a while, I'll come across code (c++) that uses a class to handle game events, but nobody has explained why they do this.

It also seems like some programming languages, like C#, automatically use a class for the program's "main."

So what I want to know is if I should be using a class for my game.  Why and/or why not?

Here's an example of what this might look like:

```
class GAME
{
public:
    void load_resources();
    bool input();
    void update();
    void draw();
};

int main ()
{
    GAME game;

    while (!quit)
    {
         quit = game.input();
         game.update();
         game.draw();
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Thanks for reading.

Comment: Do you want to use classes for your main loop? Yes? Okay, use them. You don't? Great, don't use them. There is really no "one correct way"

Comment: That style is a mental crutch for those who can't imagine program without classes, which seeped into the popular publications and tutorials "How write a game within 30 days". What really matters is not the entry point (you likely would have more complex one than this) but data model and organisation of your program, as well as how you handle APIs, portability, rendering support, possible future support of code. You'd better to read about Entity-Component-System model as well.

Comment: I would say that if you need your program to be running more then one complete game instance at the same time, then definitely the answer should be yes, encapsulate it in a class. If your program is going to run just one game instance then it's a matter of style. It won't hurt but it may be slightly more verbose than it needs to be.

Comment: I've been working on my own game in the early stages and you can take a look [here](https://github.com/Rietty/Hellcraft) for the code. While it might not be perfect, I feel like this is a solid design and is somewhat indicative of the model of most games might use, especially indie games. OOP design is all about how you think and organize your code, and while you may use classes in your code, it's more complicated than simply doing it in one class. [I suggest reading this site to familiar yourself with some patterns in game design.](http://gameprogrammingpatterns.com/contents.html).

Comment: If you have any questions feel free to open an issue on github and I'll reply best I can. Happy trails.

Answer (score 1):

In terms of game engine design we have something called a Scene system. 
A scene normally hold all the GameObjects.
When you send the scene an event it should iterate on the gameObjects and update them all with events (update start end render postrender keyboard mouse scroll resize etch).

But in a much much simpler form of the system we at least want a game class so we can reload the level.

For example when the user enters the game it may take us a min to load all the models and textures and scripts from memory so we dont want it on our main loop we may want to load async and show a loading screen in this case we'll construct the game on another thread.

Or when the user wins and go to the next level we can unload the last level so we simply destroy the Game/Scene and create a new one of the new level.

In short: this kind of approach is used to define states of our application and manage them easily